# Breeze Metadata returns null on GetMetadataFromDbContext method - EF 4.4 MVC4 WebAPI OData

Tags: breeze

I am developing an application using Breezejs, EF 4.4, MVC4, WebAPI and OData.  When breeze makes a call to the Metadata ActionMethod the result is null.  We use a code first approach and therefore do not have an EDMX file so ***I think the error comes about when breeze tries to "re-create" the EDMX in some capacity and it can't.  See below for source code where try catch produces an exception***.

**Example of runtime code where execution fails.**

```
// ~/odata/Analysis/Metadata 
[HttpGet]
public string Metadata()
{
  return _contextProvider.Metadata();
}
```

I have managed to include my project into the Breezejs repository located on GitHub.  The exception occurs on the line with code **"EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(dbContext, xwriter);"**.  I'm not sure what the issue is however the contents of the "WriteEdmx" method are below as well.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?  The only thing that I can think of is that the context that I am using is inherited from a base context which then inherits from DbContext, but other than that I am completely puzzled and at a stand still. Note: I have read that inheritance is not yet supported in breeze, but I'm not sure if that includes the contexts classes and in a separate test case I used a context that inherited from DbContext and I still received the same error.

```
private static String GetMetadataFromDbContext(Object context) {
  var dbContext = (DbContext) context;
  XElement xele;

  try {
    using (var swriter = new StringWriter()) {
      using (var xwriter = new XmlTextWriter(swriter)) {
        EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(dbContext, xwriter);
        xele = XElement.Parse(swriter.ToString());
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    if (e is NotSupportedException) {
      // DbContext that fails on WriteEdmx is likely a DataBase first DbContext.
      return GetMetadataFromObjectContext(dbContext);
    } else {
      throw;
    }
  }

  var ns = xele.Name.Namespace;
  var conceptualEle = xele.Descendants(ns + "ConceptualModels").First();
  var schemaEle = conceptualEle.Elements().First(ele => ele.Name.LocalName == "Schema");
  var xDoc = XDocument.Load(schemaEle.CreateReader());

  var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
  // This is needed because the raw edmx has a different namespace than the CLR types that it references.
  xDoc = UpdateCSpaceOSpaceMapping(xDoc, objectContext);
  return XDocToJson(xDoc);
}
```

**"WriteEdmx"**

```
// Summary:
//     Uses Code First with the given context and writes the resulting Entity Data
//     Model to the given writer in EDMX form. This method can only be used with
//     context instances that use Code First and create the model internally. The
//     method cannot be used for contexts created using Database First or Model
//     First, for contexts created using a pre-existing System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext,
//     or for contexts created using a pre-existing System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel.
//
// Parameters:
//   context:
//     The context.
//
//   writer:
//     The writer.
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1704:IdentifiersShouldBeSpelledCorrectly", MessageId = "Edmx")]
public static void WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** A downgrade from EF 4.4 to EF 4.1 seemed to have solved this problem.  An upgrade to EF 5.0 or the nightly build might also do the same.

That's the best I can do regarding this obscure issue. **#baffled**